# Selecting using subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table schema:  `company(company-name, city` . Assume that the companies may be located in several cities. Find all companies
located in every city in which 'Company X' is located.

Would this be the correct SQL code:

```
 select company name from company
 where city in (select city from company where company-name = 'Company X')
```

Is this the same as:

```
   select s.company-name
   from company s
   where not exists
   ((select city from company where company-name = 'Small Bank
   Corporation')
   except
  (select city from company t where s.company-name = t.company-name))
```

Comment: You can try to execute the query yourself to see if result is correct, it probably won't kill you.

Comment: A subquery is part of the requirement?

Comment: does the company have to be in every city that `Company X` is in? or just any city?

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use a join

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.company_name
FROM company AS c1
JOIN company AS c2 ON c1.city = c2.city
WHERE c2.company_name = 'Company X'
```

Answer (score -1):

If your field is called "company-name" the query should be

```
select "company-name" 
from company 
where city in (select city from company where "company-name" = 'Company X')
```

If the company's name know it's unique you can replace the "in" operator with "="

Comment: Double quotes are for strings, not column names. In MySQL you use backticks around column names that contain special characters.

Comment: I juse tried `select * FROM myTable WHERE "username" = 'barmar'` in my database and it didn't find the row.

Comment: See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2c3c/1. Only the second query succeeds. Maybe there's a SQL mode setting that changes this, to match ANSI SQL.

Comment: It depends on the [ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) SQL mode.